# detect face from google vision API and crop face

Tags: android, google-api, face-detection, cropimage.net

i have find face area from image using android vision API. but how to crop face from live camera. [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)

Comment: you can create a bitmap base on the Overlay top,bottom,left & right from the image captured.

Comment: How can you have code.

Comment: any approach???

Comment: checkout the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491289/how-to-crop-and-save-detected-faces-using-mobile-vision

Answer (score 0):

You can use takePicture method for getting image

```
    mCameraSource.takePicture(new CameraSource.ShutterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onShutter() {

        }
    }, new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {
         //Your code for crop faces here
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, opt); croppedFace = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, (int) facePosition.x, (int) facePosition.y, (int) faceWidth, (int) faceHeight); but it doesn't crop the correct position, can you please help?